# jQuery JSON Response is wrapped in html

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am requesting some JSON for an autocomplete feature. Unfortunately the JSON is wrapped with a html span tag. This happens due to a poor backend library written in VB, which is not changed by the operator within the next few months. So I have to get rid off the html span tag in another way. Here is my JS call and the response:

```
module.props.functions.ajaxSearchon = function (currVal) {
    // Search on Type
    $.ajax({
      url: module.props.apiURLs.searchOnType  + '?query=' + currVal + '&lang=' + module.props.lang,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
        module.state = {
          searchResult: result,
          searchQuery: currVal
        };
      },

      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        module.state = $.extend(module.state, {
          searchResults: 'no results found'
        });
        console.log("error", module.state);
      },

      complete: function () {
        module.props.functions.refreshSearchResults();
      }
    })
  };
```

It works excellent with well formed JSON as response. But my response looks like this:

```
<span id="fromContext">
{
  "results": [  
  {
    "headline": "headline text",
    "summary": " <em>summary</em> result text",
    "url": "/url/to/page",
    "image": {
      "url": "/media.jpg",
      "alt": "media alt text"
    },
    "count": ""
  },
  {
    "headline": "empty object"
  }
  ],
"hasmore": true
}
</span>
```

So, I would be able to detect the span (because it has an ID), but I dont know how to access the JSON part of the whole response with the ajax request. I think this main problem is, that the ajax call results in an error, because the response isn't JSON...
Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the ajax.dataType attribute to "text" and the contentType to "text/plain"

```
  contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "text",
```

and convert the response string to a jquery object

```
const $responseObject = $(response);
```

and then you can access the valid json with

```
let text = $responseObject.text();
```

and process it further.